# Why doesn't 'shell' work in VBscript in VS6?

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript

In a macro for Visual Studio 6, I wanted to run an external program, so I typed:

```
shell("p4 open " + ActiveDocument.FullName)
```

Which gave me a type mismatch runtime error. What I ended up having to type was this:

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strResult = wshShell.Run("p4 open " + ActiveDocument.FullName)
```

What is going on here? Is that nonsense really necessary or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [lassevk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272/why-doesnt-shell-work-in-vbscript-in-vs6#20304) pointed out, VBScript is not Visual Basic.

I believe the only built in object in VBScript is the WScript object.

```
WScript.Echo "Hello, World!"
```

From the docs

> The WScript object is the root object of the Windows Script Host
>   object model hierarchy. It never needs to be instantiated before invoking its
>   properties and methods, and it is always available from any script file.

Everything else must be created via the CreateObject call.  Some of those objects are [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f51wc7hz(VS.85).aspx).

The Shell object is one of the *other* objects that you need to create if you want to call methods on it.

One caveat, is that RegExp is *sort of* built in, in that you can instantiate a RegExp object like so in VBScript:

```
Dim r as New RegExp
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript isn't Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Shell "p4 open" & ActiveDocument.FullName
```

Answer (score -1):

VB6 uses & to concatenate strings rather than +, and you'll want to make sure the file name is encased in quotes in case of spaces.  Try it like this:

```
Shell "p4 open """ & ActiveDocument.FullName & """"
```